# how to append name and integer fro variable in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some pandas variables like esl0,esl1,esl2,esl3 to read and all of them are pandas Dataframe.

so i am going to read them in for loop like:

`([print('esl' + str(i),min(esli['MessageID'])) for i in range(0,3)]`

but i got the erro **esli is not defined** how can i solve it? i tried other solution like the following:

```
filenames = ['esl'+str(i) for i in range(0,3)]
for i in filenames:
    print(i,min(i['MessageID']))
```

but i got this error **TypeError: string indices must be integers**
how can i solve it?

thanks in advance

Comment: replace `esli` with `globals()['esl' + str(i)]`

Comment: As per the code snippet you provided above, you have declared the variables as strings.
You are trying to access the "MessageID" in those string variables. Hence you are getting the error "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Answer (score 1):

As you can see that the variable `esl0`, `esl1` and `esl2` are stored `globally` in this `namespace`. In python to access the any global variable it have a function `globals()` which return a `dict-object` which store all variable as key and their corresponding data as value. You can see the comment of [@Cyttorak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67815580/how-to-append-name-and-integer-fro-variable-in-python#comment119866908_67815580) user.

**Update :**

```
filenames = ['esl'+str(i) for i in range(0,3)]
```

**To:**

```
filenames = [globals()['esl' + str(i)] for i in range(0,3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable i here is a string (filenames: "esl0", "esl1", "esl2"). You can't do i['MessageID'] because it would be something like "esl0"['MessageID'].